# Tool or method to adjust static font sizes in CSS? (global relative adjustment, but keep static)

Tags: html, css, drupal, editor

Are there any good tricks or tools for adjusting all the font sizes in a style sheet (.css) together in a relative way?

Specifically, I am using a custom style sheet (used with a Drupal theme) that has numerous font sizes defined in absolute terms.  E.g. 13px, 18px, etc.

Rather than going through and empirically adding a few px to each, I'd like to find an editor or script that makes some intelligent suggestions to tweak them up or down.

Ie. easily change

```
body {
...
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
...
}
h1, .h1 {
  ...
  font-size: 23px;
  ...
}
h2, .h2 {
  ...
  font-size: 15px;
  ...
}
```

to

```
    body {
...
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: **16px**;
...
}
h1, .h1 {
  ...
  font-size: **28px**;
  ...
}
h2, .h2 {
  ...
  font-size: **17px**;
  ...
}
```

in a visual or quick way.

Note:
-Other ways to do this would be to edit all font references to use "em" as a unit, or to % sizes.  E.g.

```
BODY {font-size: 100%;}
#intro {font-size: .9em;}
#content {font-size: .8em;}
```

However, I am looking for a way to keep these absolute, in pixels, but adjust them all together.

In part, because I am relatively a novice at CSS. But also because the sheet was created by a collaborator and I want to make minimal changes to avoid breaking some other functionality without knowing it.

Specifics: Drupal 7, Mac OSX as a dev machine, already using Firebug to see changes.
I don't mind buying a tool to do this, although I note that several of the best CSS viewers at least seem free.

Thanks!
David

Comment: Unfortunately you can't (unless you're using a CSS preprocessor). `em`-s and `rem`-s are the only way.

Answer (score 0):

It is clever in the current web universe to design with mobile devices in mind, and font size is also something to consider. Instead of making your site look gigantic on a 480x320 screen, the site would lower itself down to the default font size of the browser or system.

That would be writing all your CSS with `em` and `rem` units (as well as `%` when we're talking about containers). `px` should work for graphical apps that need strict coordinates to operate, and only for that.

However, if you've gone all the way with `px`, I believe recent jQuery versions can add and subtract CSS `px` units as though they were integers. Since this is just a guess and we're not supposed to give guesses as answers, here goes another way, also using jQuery:

```js
function changeAllFonts(ratio) {
  $("*")
    .css(
      "font-size",
      function(index, value) {
        var newVal = parseInt(value.replace("px", ""));
        newVal *= ratio;
        newCSS = newVal + "px";
        return newCSS;
      }
    );
}
```

This gets `value`, the current CSS value of `* { font-size:`**`value`**`}`, so don't forget to set one if you will use this approach. Just execute the function on document load this way:

```js
$( ).ready(changeAllFonts(1.8));
```

...for example. The `ratio` parameter is actually a multiplier of the current values.

Best of luck!